# Apache POI: getRow() Returns null although sheet contains non-empty rows

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to read rows from an Excel sheet which contains 148 rows. None of these rows are empty. When I use sheet.getRow(0), the result is null. The same situation occurs with sheet.getRow(47). However, starting from sheet.getRow(48), it returns the correct value.

Here is a code:

```
public void resizeColumns(){
        if(workbook == null){
            return;
        }
        var numberOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSheets; i++) {
            var sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
            if (sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() > 0) {
                var row = sheet.getRow(sheet.getFirstRowNum());
                if(row != null){
                    var cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                        var cell = cellIterator.next();
                        int columnIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();
                        if (sheet instanceof SXSSFSheet) {
                            ((SXSSFSheet) sheet).trackColumnForAutoSizing(columnIndex);
                        }
                        sheet.autoSizeColumn(columnIndex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm using SXSSFWorkbook

problem line:

```
var row = sheet.getRow(sheet.getFristRowNum())
```

I was trying to debug this method and observed the behavior I described above.

Comment: Are you sure you're reading the sheet you think you're reading? What happens if you print out the name of the sheet?

Comment: `SXSSF` is not made for reading but only for writing. See https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf: "SXSSF achieves its low memory footprint by limiting access to the rows that are within a sliding window, while XSSF gives access to all rows in the document. Older rows that are no longer in the window become inaccessible, as they are written to the disk."